# How to deal with non-consecutive (non-daily) dates in R, while looping?

Tags: r, loops, date

I am trying to write a script that loops through month-end dates and compares associated fields, but I am unable to find a way to way to do this.

I have my data in a flatfile and subset based on 'TheDate'

For instance I have:

```
date.range <- subset(raw.data, observation_date == theDate)
```

Say `TheDate = 2007-01-31`

I want to find the next month included in my data flatfile which is 2007-02-28. How can I reference this in my loop?

I currently have:

```
date.range.t1 <- subset(raw.data, observation_date == theDate+1)
```

This doesnt work obviously as my data is not daily.

EDIT: 
To make it more clear, my data is like below

```
ticker  observation_date    Price
   ADB   31/01/2007             1
   ALS   31/01/2007             2
   ALZ   31/01/2007             3
   ADB   28/02/2007             2
   ALS   28/02/2007             5
   ALZ   28/02/2007             1
```

I am using a loop so I want to skip from 31/01/2007 to 29/02/2007 by recognising it is the next date, and use that value to subset my data

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output.  This is not clear.

Comment: In addition to what @akrun said, you should also look into the `lubridate` package.

Comment: thanks, have clarified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get unique values of date like so:

```
unique_dates<-unique(raw.data$observation_date)
```

The sort these unique dates:

```
unique_dates_ordered<-unique_dates[order(as.Date(unique_dates, format="%Y-%m-%d"))]
```

Now you can subset based on the index of unique_dates_ordered i.e.

```
subset(raw.data, raw.data$observation_date == unique_dates_ordered[i])
```

Where i = 1 for the first value, i = 2 for the second value etc.

Comment: thanks for the response. my data is not unique - there are multiple lines of data corresponding to each date. I am trying to subset all of the rows that have a certain date and loop for the next date

Comment: Exactly, thats why I recommend using the `unique()` function as above. That will give you a list of the unique dates that are in your data set. That list will be called "unique_dates". The next step orders that list of dates and creates a new list called "unique_dates_ordered". You can then use that list to subset on as shown in the last step. So your loop would look something like this:

Comment: ` for(i in 1:length(unique_dates_ordered){    your_subset <- subset(raw.data, raw.data$observation_date == unique_dates_ordered[i])}`

Comment: @Phoebe Can we close this question and mark above as the answer?